# Checkstyle plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, checkstyle

Is there a specification that rules Checkstyle plugins across different Java development platforms?

I work at a company that uses this one from eclipse:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug
but I would like to try IntelliJ IDEA Community.

I know that IntelliJ has many Checkstyle options, but I would like to know if they are going to behave the same if a checkstyle xml file is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a DTD configuration you need to include.

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd">
```

That will tell you which modules you can use to produce a valid checkstyle xml.